# Typescript 5 errors

Tags: angular, typescript

I am trying to use highcharts in Angular 16/Typescript 5.

Code copied from Highchart:

```
this.time = this.dataList.map((e) => Date.parse(e.timestamp));
```

Which then returns the error:

> Error: src/app/parts/test_page.part.ts:152:32 - error TS7006:
> Parameter 'e' implicitly has an 'any' type.
>
> 152 this.time = this.dataList.map((e) => Date.parse(e.timestamp));

or the code:

```
    this.dataValue = this.dataList.map((e) => e.value);
```

returns:

> Error: src/app/parts/test_page.part.ts:153:41 - error TS7006:
> Parameter 'e' implicitly has an 'any' type.
>
> 153     this.dataValue = this.dataList.map((e) => e.value);

A different example is:

Your Code:

```
    formatter: function () {
        return formatDate(
          this.value,
          "MM/dd/yyyy '<br/>'hh:mm:ss aa",
          'en-US'
        );
      },
```

Returns these errors:

> Error: src/app/parts/test_page.part.ts:203:9 - error TS7023:
> 'formatter' implicitly has return type 'any' because it does not have
> a return type annotation and is referenced directly or indirectly in
> one of its return expressions.
>
> 203         formatter: function () {
> ~~~~~~~~~
>
> Error: src/app/parts/test_page.part.ts:204:42 - error TS2339: Property
> 'point' does not exist on type '{ formatter: () => any; pointFormat:
> string; }'.
>
> 204           console.log('this.point', this.point);
> ~~~~~
>
> Error: src/app/parts/test_page.part.ts:206:18 - error TS2339: Property
> 'point' does not exist on type '{ formatter: () => any; pointFormat:
> string; }'.
>
> 206             this.point.category,
> ~~~~~

I am trying to move an application from Angular 4 to Angular 16.

Comment: Try adding the keyword any to the parameters/ return values in question. AFAIK as I know, Typescript 5 enabled a lot of strict compile time checks which weren't enabled by default before. That's why the code might not compile in a new project. And are you trying to migrate from angular 4 to 16 all at once? Oo

Comment: I should have shown where the dataList array was defined.  It is defined as:   var dataList: any = [
  {      value:  1.610886,      timestamp: '2022-04-22T06:49:20Z',    },
  {      value:  2.610886,      timestamp: '2022-04-22T06:51:20Z',    },
  I just reworked my test case to not need the map function

Comment: As far as the formatter issue goes, I would just like to know which TS flas can be changed, or what the code change should be to make the example work.

Comment: I know moving from Angular 4 is a JOB, but so far I have been able to work through it.  Where I am getting lost is when I try to copy example code that supposedly works to a clean environment and it still does not work.

Comment: `this.dataList.map((e:any) => e.value);` See the `e:any`

Comment: Ahh, thanks Eliseo.  That is my problem.  You solved one of my issues.